# Cannot change labels using listbox selected item via class

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, listbox

I have a listbox which holds a name of a tag from and xml file, there are other tags which are also held in a class but when I try to click on a value inside the listbox to set my label text to what the value is inside of the class I get the following error: "InvalidCastException was unhandled. Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Coursework1.modules'."
Heres the code, this is inside the listbox event for when the index has changed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectionBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (selectionBox.GetSelected(i) == true)
            {
                infoLabel.Text = ((modules)selectionBox.Items[i]).mInfo;
                lectureSlotLabel.Text = ((modules)selectionBox.Items[i]).mLSlot;
                tutorialLabel.Text = ((modules)selectionBox.Items[i]).mTSlot;
                prerequisiteLabel.Text = ((modules)selectionBox.Items[i]).mPreReq;
                codeLabel.Text = ((modules)selectionBox.Items[i]).mCode;
                nameLabel.Text =((modules)selectionBox.Items[i]).mName;
            }
        }
```

//Selection box creation

```
       String workingDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(workingDir + @"\XML.xml");
        textReader.Read();
        XmlNodeType type;

        while (textReader.Read())
        {
            textReader.MoveToElement();
            type = textReader.NodeType;
            if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                //if (textReader.Name == "Code")
                //{
                //    module.Add(new modules(textReader.ReadElementContentAsString(),
                //        textReader.ReadElementContentAsString(),
                //        textReader.ReadElementContentAsString(),
                //        textReader.ReadElementContentAsString(),
                //        textReader.ReadElementContentAsString(),
                //        textReader.ReadElementContentAsString(),
                //        textReader.ReadElementContentAsString()));
                //}


                if (textReader.Name == "Code")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    code = textReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(code);

                }
                if (textReader.Name == "Name")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    name = textReader.Value;
                    //selectionBox.Items.Add(name);
                    Console.WriteLine(name);

                }
                if (textReader.Name == "Semester")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    semester = textReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(semester);

                }
                if (textReader.Name == "Prerequisite")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    preReq = textReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(code);
                }
                if (textReader.Name == "LectureSlot")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    lSlot = textReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(lSlot);
                }
                if (textReader.Name == "TutorialSlot")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    tSlot = textReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(tSlot);
                }
                if (textReader.Name == "Info")
                {
                    textReader.Read();
                    info = textReader.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(info);
                    module.Add(new Modules(code, name, semester, tSlot, lSlot, info, preReq));
                }


            }


            //Console.WriteLine(module);

        }
        foreach (object o in module)
        {
            Modules m = (Modules)o;
            //String hold = m.mName;
            selectionBox.Items.Add(m.mName);
        }
        textReader.Close();
```

//Label text being used

```
var xmlFile = XDocument.Load(xmlDirectory + @"\XML.xml");
        //Finds the XML file again and looks for the Name tag
        var mName = from directory in xmlFile.Descendants("Name")
                    where directory.Value == (String)selectionBox.SelectedItem
                    select directory.Parent.Element("Name").Value;
        //in the mName we search the directory for the Name tag and after we search
        //for the selected item of the list in the directory after that we look for 
        //the "Name" element in the directory and that gets the name value and saves it to
        //mName
        foreach (var item in mName)
        {
            //use the loop to make it dynamic as when the selected item changes so does,
            //the moduleName label
            nameLabel.Text = item.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: casting the same thing to the same type 10 times. EPIC.

Comment: Also, complete lack of C# naming conventions. Type names must be `Proper Cased` (I.E `Modules` instead of `modules`). And Why do your properties / fields have an `m` prefix??

Comment: They have the 'm' prefix for module and I have changed the class name to modules, apologies.

Comment: @HighCore could you please tell me what you meant by the first casting thing?

Comment: Can you show the code for where the `selectionBox` is being populated?

Comment: @nick_w I have added the code where I populated selectionBox, the Modules class has properties where I get an set.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
selectionBox.Items.Add(m.mName);
```

Is merely ading the name of the `module` to `selectionBox`, which would explain why you were having problems trying to cast a `string` to a `module`. What you need to look into is using databinding. Add this code in place of the `foreach (object o in module)` loop:

```
selectionBox.DataSource = module;
selectionBox.DisplayMember = "mName";
```

And in the index changed event you can retrieve the selected item like this:

```
modules m = (modules)selectionBox.SelectedItem;
```

Further, if you do retrieve the selected item in this way you can do away with the `for` loop you currently have in the index changed event handler.

**Edit:**

Currently you are adding the names of each `module` to the `selectionBox`. However, when you go to retrieve the selected item, you are getting an error as you are attempting to cast the name of the object to the actual object.

So using my solution:

```
selectionBox.DataSource = module;
```

Assigns the list of objects you create to be the `DataSource` (i.e., where it gets its data from) of `selectionBox`, and

```
selectionBox.DisplayMember = "mName";
```

Indicates which property of the object should be used as the display text. In this case I have `mName` as this was the property you were previously adding to `selectionBox`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean? If it helps I have a submit button in the form which creates an XML and saves the values I have selected and moved to another list and displays them correctly.

Comment: @user2157179 Which bit do you not understand?

Comment: Well I have just added the code you suggested however got an error saying "Coursework1.Form1.module is a field but is used like a type" and the thing I dont understand is what is happening, so in the "selectionBox.DataSource = module;
selectionBox.DisplayMember = "mName";" am I adding the mName to the listbox I cannot check this because I get an error.

Comment: @user2157179 See my edit. Also, where are you getting that error message?

Comment: I have tried a few things that you have said separately, firstly if I just fill the selectionList with the above code I get an error whenever I use a button which has to do with the selectionBox I get an error, but they only show I run the code. If I add both parts I get the error I mentioned above.

Comment: @user2157179 That `Coursework1.Form1.module is a field but is used like a type` error should be fixable by performing a correct cast. I'm a little unsure of your variable names by something like: `modules m = (modules)selectionBox.SelectedItem;` should work.

Comment: Right ok I will attempt that later, as I have come up with a pseudo correction by using LINQ and thus changing the labels, however it is an issue when I am trying to use the values in the button which I need it, as I need a foreach statement but cannot use it because I cannot have the selected value. Instead I have to use it on the 'submit' button to be able to use it.

Comment: @user2157179 I'm not sure what you mean there. You say "I cannot have the selected value". Is this referring to my code for retrieving the selected item?

Comment: Its not to do with your code as I could not get that working however, but what I meant by the selected value was that in using LINQ I cannot access the value I will add the code I have used to change the label text.

Comment: @user2157179 I think it would be best just to focus on the specific problem you described in the question. With that in mind, which bit of my code didn't work?

Comment: the modules m = (modules)selectionBox.SelectedItem; gives me an error.

Comment: @user2157179 In that case you need to perform the cast correctly. Replace `modules` with the name of the class. I'm not 100% sure of the exact class name, but what about replacing it with `Modules`, giving you: `Modules m = (Modules)selectionBox.SelectedItem;`?

Answer (score -3):

This is not the answer to the question per se, but an answer to a question posted by the OP in the comment:

> @HighCore could you please tell me what you meant by the first casting
>   thing?

you shouldn't do

`((modules))selectionBox.Items[i]`

many times. Instead, replace that by

```
if (selectionBox.GetSelected(i) == true)
{
    var module = selectionBox.Items[i] as modules; 

    if (module != null)
    {
        infoLabel.Text = module.mInfo;
        //etc...
    }
}
```

This is simpler and also safer (because I'm actually checking that the thing is a `modules` to begin with. That prevents casting exceptions.

Comment: I have tried what you said, this time I do not get an error however the thing I am aiming to do i.e. change the label depending on which list item is highlighted does not work. I know what I have put in the first code does work as it has worked in another program, and it was the same process.